# Web-cams, Java, Streaming.

Tags: java, webcam

I need to set up live streaming from a number of web-cameras to the internet (in browsers), and the streams should be visible only to particular users. I.e. user A logs in to my system with his or her login/password, goes to the video stream page, and sees the stream from a particular cam, and other users cannot see that video, even if they know the url to that stream.

I've looked at a number of solutions so far, but some of them are obsolete, most of them are for image processing, recognition and the like, and some are just a bit too cumbersome, like Red5, for example.

Is there a relatively simple solution for that, that would just allow me to get a videostream from a particular cam connected to my computer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Linux I have had success with V4L4J (Video 4 Linux 4 Java) which is small and really quite cool. You would need to do quite a bit of work to get streaming working for a low bandwidth connection but if it is over LAN playing back an MJPEG stream over a TCP socket is easy beans :-)

http://code.google.com/p/v4l4j/

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is not a priority any more, but I will look at it later. The documentation certainly implies that it is a tempting thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) to communicate with your cam.